# jQuery hover animate & click problem

Tags: jquery, click, hover, jquery-animate

have a list of images as a navigation. when you hover over them a div with transparent background slides up. when you hover out the div slides down.

that part wokes like a charm.

now when you click on the image or title, the div with the title changes its opacity to 1, moves to the top of the image and gains 100% height.

the problem is when i hover out the title div hides again. so how can i stop the hover out effect on click?

i already tried a view solutions to similar problems but didn't get to work.. i'm quite new to jQuery so any help would be appriciated.

here is the code so far with a try using .unbind:

```
var thumbslide = $('.boxgrid.captionfull').hover(
    function() { //Hover over
        $(this).children('.cover').stop().animate({'top':'130px'},{queue:false,duration:350});
    },function() { //Hover out
        $(this).children('.cover').stop().animate({'top':'230px'},{queue:false,duration:350});
    }
    ).click(function() {
        $(this).children('.cover').stop().animate({'top':'0px', height:"230px", opacity:"1"},{queue:false,duration:350}).unbind('mouseleave');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're unbind the *children*, not the element you're on.  Rearrange it like this:

```
$(this).unbind('mouseleave').children('.cover').stop().animate({'top':'0px', height:"230px", opacity:"1"},{queue:false,duration:350});
```

Comment: thats a clever move. thanks for the tip. but now the clicked status on one item remains when i click another one. so in this case i guess i have to bind the click again?

Comment: @tobiasmay - try this out, have to run so can't test at the moment, but should work: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/snAae/

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but sadly the class "clicked" stays, once the div is clicked.

Comment: i'm setting this question to answered, since nicks answer solved that first problem. i'll open a new question for the following problem. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you could simple check the widht or opacity on hover out...

inside the hover out function you do

```
if($(this).children('.cover').css('opacity')!=1){
$(this).children('.cover').stop().animate({'top':'230px'},{queue:false,duration:350});
}
```

Comment: hmm.. works as well sorta the way it should.. but when i hover over the clicked element it animates to the first hover over state. and it stays at top aswell when i click another element..